# What are some good examples of a WS-Eventing client in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, ws-eventing

There are a few web service frameworks available for Java: Axis2, CXF, JBossWS, and Metro. Does anyone have some good examples of a WS-Eventing client with these frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Apache Savan](http://ws.apache.org/savan/source-repository.html). It's was a publisher/subscriber implementation for Axis2 that supported WS-Eventing (see [sample.eventing.Client](https://github.com/apache/savan/blob/trunk/modules/samples/eventing/src/sample/eventing/Client.java) for an example client) but was retired in 2014.

JBossWS has some information about setting up a service [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/user-guide/en/html/1.0.4/en/html/wseventing.html), but I didn't see any example for a client. Regarding CXF is includes support for eventing although it uses native types, nothing from JAX-WS.

Comment: I guess Savan never took off; your first link redirects to a project page with no useful info, and the other two links give 404s.